# Java 2d drawLine slow for long lines

Tags: java, awt, drawing, java-2d

I have a piece of code that needs to draw many thousands of lines (between 6000 and 50000).

An unrelated bug that I have subsequently fixed, exposed something interesting; namely, when these lines are very long (say 30k pixels) the drawLine function takes up 95% of my codes time, compared with when the lines are only 1000 pixels long, when it takes up only 15% of the time.

The lines are the same colour, fixed width (1px)

Why are long line draws so slow? What options do I have for speeding this up, not just for the long lines, are there rendering hints that can be used? I am already running this threaded.

Comment: You could draw the lines to a backing buffer (using a `BufferedImage`), but this may not resolve the issue.  Without knowing the underlying implementing of the actually physically drawing process, it's impossible to know.  The next question might be, why do you need lines so long?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Typically I don't (not 30k) but I do still need to draw really long lines (visualisation of large networks), but I do need to draw lines that are a few thousand long in the larger networks, if I can leverage a small improvement per line in the average case, that will be huge. Its odd, drawing the lines (even the "fast" ones) takes longer than the combined time of building the network, discovering it's structure and running a layout algorithm.

Comment: YakumoYukari gave excellent advice: if any of your line segments are outside of your display viewport, that could hurt performance.  Clipping before drawing could definitely help.  OTHERWISE: you might want to consider a different graphics library, e.g. [JOGGLE](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) or [LWJGL](http://www.lwjgl.org/)

Comment: @FoggyDay very few edges are (mostly the short ones), what happens when I scroll the viewport, does it need to repaint all newly visible lines again?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the java drawline function, when you draw a line into NEW territory (I.E. it's only rendered a 300x300 area but you draw a line out to 200,500), it has to initialize all those pixels to drawable area.

Here's a snippet from a similar answer:

"I suggest you to calculate the visible part of the painting area (using either JComponent's getVisibleRect () method or Graphics g.getClip ().getBounds () method) and limit your paintings with only that area.

That small optimization could speedup component's painting in times if it is really large (for example with 10000x10000 pixels component's area)."

Comment: Interesting, the lines in this case all go from opposite ends of a circle, so the bounds of the rectangle will not change.